# org-mode: exporting a subtree to latex still parses latex header commands defined in other subtrees

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, latex-header

I have an org-mode file made of several headings whose structure can be summarized as follows:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: <some global latex commands>

* Heading A 
  #+LATEX_HEADER: <some latex commands>
  <text>
* Heading B
  #+LATEX_HEADER: <some other latex commands>
  <text>
```

Each heading thus inserts specific additional commands in the header of the exported document.

If I try export say "Heading A" with `C-c C-e C-s` to export only its corresponding subtree, the exported latex file (or pdf after compilation) contains the set of commands defined in "Heading B". Is there a way to avoid this and be sure that `#+LATEX_HEADER:` is not parsed in subtrees that are not related to the one exported? Or maybe I need to use another command than `#+LATEX_HEADER:` but then how to ensure that the commands are added to the LaTeX preamble?

Thank you.

---

Update: the issue is solved if I replace `#+LATEX_HEADER:` by `#+LATEX:` but then it is not a header command anymore.

Comment: Keyword options like `#+LATEX_HEADER` are global in scope: it does not matter *where* you put them in the file. Precisely for that reason, the recommendation is to put them at the top of the file. That includes most options in [Export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html) and for LaTeX, all options in [LaTeX specific export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-export-settings.html). You can explicitly COMMENT each section that you are not exporting, but that is admittedly awkward. What benefit would you get from making `#+LATEX_HEADER` subtree-specific?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Assuming that ```#+LATEX``` allows me to add latex commands where they are defined in the (exported)document while  ```#+LATEX_HEADER:``` allows modifying the preamble, the benefit of having this last command locally parsed would be, for instance, to be able load different packages according to the current subtree. I guess this could conflict with a global compilation of the document though, where all packages from all subtrees would be then loaded. Maybe another command, that is not called at global compilation, would be needed, such as a ``#+LATEX_HEADER_LOCAL:``

Comment: But it does not matter (much) if all of the packages are loaded, even though a particular subtree doesn't use all of them. You need them in any case for the whole document, so all you are paying for the subtree compilation is LaTeX taking a little longer to compile because it has to read a few extra files. Having a `#+LATEX_HEADER_LOCAL` would complicate the Org LaTeX exporter: it would have to go back and modify the preamble when it comes up to one. The current exporter writes the output in one pass: it would have to be modified to go back and fix things up.

Comment: I see. In fact, some packages may conflict with other, moreover, there isn't only package you can define in the preamble; you can define different commands, environments, different package options, ... that's why it could be useful to get such a local scope.